# Can not submit a form using javascript

Tags: javascript

The hyper link as a submit button is not working.
I think the error may be this  `<a href="javascript:subForm('myform')">`.
I don't know whether this line accept string 'myform' as parameter.
Thanks for your help.

JS

```
function valid(form) {
  if (form.passwd1.value == "") {
    alert("Please enter the password")
    form.passwd1.focus()
    return false
  }
  if (form.passwd1.value != form.passwd2.value) {
    alert("Passwords do not match");
    form.passwd1.focus()
    form.passwd1.select()
    return false
  }
  return true
}

function subForm(form){
  if( valid(document.form)){
    document.form.submit();
  }
}
```

Form

```
<form action="abc.html" name="myform">
  Your name: <input type="text" size="30" />
  <p>Choose a password: <input type="password" name="passwd1" /></p>
  <p>Verify password: <input type="password" name="passwd2" /></p>
  <a href="javascript:subForm('myform')"><img src="images/submit.jpg"/></a>
</form>
```

Comment: *"The hyper link as a submit button is not working."* Please be more precise. What have you done to debug the problem? If I try to run the code, I get `TypeError: form is undefined`. Have you verified which value `document.form` returns? The question you should be asking is "how can I access a property whose name is contained in a variable". And this question has been asked before many times.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the form through as a parameter just validate the fields directly in valid(), i.e.

```
if (myform.passwd1.value == "") ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting form by `formName`, you should use `document.forms[formName]`. Your `subForm` function should change to:

```
function subForm(formName) {
  var form = document.forms[formName];

  if (typeof form !== 'undefined' && valid(form)) {
     form.submit();
  }
}
```